# Open Source single sign on project

Tags: c#, authentication, single-sign-on, dotnetopenauth

I was looking into OAuth then stumbled upon ThinkTecture github repositories.

I am interested in authentication and authorization just like Stackoverflow and looking for open source projects to somewhat use and build on.

Is stackoverflow single sign on project open sourced?

Or what are some alternatives can you recommend.

PS. I want to authenticate against Active Directory of my organization.

Comment: SO is not open sourced. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you would be to use Active Directory Federation Services 2.0.

ADFS2 is a free Windows Server component that offers federation sso services for Active Directory accounts. The sso is based on the WS-Federation protocol which many services use natively (Sharepoint Server, Office365). By bridging ADFS with other identity providers (OAuth, Shibboleth) you can create arbitrarily complex federation scenarios.

I am not sure if SO acts like the identity provider (i.e. you can authenticate agaist it). And even if it does, it would use one of enterprise and widely accepted sso protocols: OAUth2, WS-Federation, Shibboleth, SAML. If you seek knowledge on these, ask, search, read as people use these protocols daily.